# Play 2.0.4: Any chance to set followRedirects to false in WS.Response in Java controller?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I need to make w WS call to handle HEAD request by myself, anyway it always get's response AFTER redirection (so finally I get always 200 status instead of ie. 301)

In documentation it's written that I should set `ws.followRedirects=false` in my application.conf, anyway it doesn't seem to work. I can see that Scala version is trying read this config, however I have a Java controller. Also can't switch to 2.1 now, where as I can see there is special setter for the issue.

Is there ANY workaround ?

Comment: Have you tried with a Scala controller? In 2.0.4 you can mix them without a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'v no Scala experience, I'll do it if there will be no other option.

Comment: Well then it's time to learn Scala ;) Sorry, no idea what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Scala from Java. The method `wsHead` encapsulates the Scala code and delivers only Objects from the Java Play API. Migrated to Play 2.1.0 you can refactor that method.

```
package controllers;

import play.api.libs.ws.Response;
import play.api.libs.ws.WS$;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.WS;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        final String url = "http://localhost:80";
        final F.Promise<WS.Response> responsePromise = wsHead(url);
        return async(responsePromise.map(new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result apply(WS.Response response) throws Throwable {
                return ok("got status: " + response.getStatus());
            }
        }));
    }

    private static F.Promise<WS.Response> wsHead(String url) {
        return new F.Promise(WS$.MODULE$.url(url).head()).map(new F.Function<Response, WS.Response>() {
            @Override
            public WS.Response apply(Response o) throws Throwable {
                return new WS.Response(o.getAHCResponse());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You still need to add `ws.followRedirects=false` in your application.conf.

Comment: Thank you for sample, anyway for the purpose with my poor Scala knowledge it will be easier to move the action to Scala controller instead of mixing Scala and Java ;) (at least for me)